# Can I convert many rss feeds to single JSON file?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, rss, winjs

I am working with windows 8 app using **Java Script**

I have few rss feeds, like:

1. http://dmadmin.dailymirror.lk/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=16&format=raw
2. http://dmadmin.dailymirror.lk/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=17&format=raw

Following function get each rss feed and convert to a JSON object..But I want to do is get all rss feed to one JSON object. (there is two rss feeds. So after the function call it gave me two separate JSON objects. But I want one object)

```
    for (x = 0; x < listOfFeed.length; x++) {
        //loop x start
        feedburnerUrl = listOfFeed[x].url,
            feedUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q=" + encodeURIComponent(feedburnerUrl);

        WinJS.xhr({
            url: feedUrl,
            responseType: "rss/json"
        }).done(function complete(result) { //result = [object XMLHttpRequest]  for the requested URLs                                                                                   
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);  //jsonData = [object Object] create Object
            var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed.entries; //entries = [object object][object object][object object]......

            entries.forEach(function (entry) { // process the entries...                                

               console.log('{"title" :"' + entry.title + '","Date":"' + entry.publishedDate + '"},');                          
            });
        });
    }  //loop x finish
}
```

1. listOfFeed = array of the rss url.
2. entries = each object in the full JSON object (there is 25 items inside one URL).
3. jsonData = JSON format of the each url. So I got two.But I want one JSON object for these two urls.

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.concat()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#concat) to join the entries arrays.  You can also track the number of outstanding requests and then process the entries when it reaches 0.  Something like:

```
var allEntries = [];
var pendingRequestCount = listOfFeed.length;

var onRequestFinished = function() {
  pendingRequestCount--;

  if (pendingRequestCount === 0) {
    allEntries.forEach(function (entry) { // process the entries...                                
      console.log('{"title" :"' + entry.title + '","Date":"' + entry.publishedDate + '"},');                          
    });
  }
};

for (x = 0; x < listOfFeed.length; x++) {
  ... // Same as before
  }).done(function complete(result) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);  
    var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed.entries; 

    allEntries = allEntries.concat(entries);

    onRequestFinished();        
  });
}  //loop x finish
```

You should also handle failed requests and call the onRequestFinished function as well.

Comment: Thank your very much for your kindness @nkron. One question. As you said earlier how I sort all the entries according to the published date? where to add that method..? I use add it to a previous place. But it sort each feed only.

Comment: Actually I can sort allEntries.. Then I got the result which I want. Thank you very much @nkron. I'm new to this field and hope your help in future also.. Thank you again.

Comment: @robi kumar, Thank you for editing my question neatly.. Thank your very much